# csv to mysql in reverse order

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a CSV file that contains multiple entries roughly 1000s that comes from another source. Unfortunately the way its generated it puts the most recent transactions first.  I want to append the data into mysql but its in the wrong order. How do i fix that?
The only way i could think was to write it to a temp table the query by date ASC and insert back into the correct table. Is there a better way?

```
   $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/assets/csv/";
    $year = trim(date('Y', strtotime($start)));
    $month = trim(date('m', strtotime($start))-1);
    $day = trim(date('d', strtotime($start)));

    $file = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=". $symbol ."&a=". $month ."&b=". $day ."&c=". $year;
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $fp = fopen($location . $symbol.'.csv', 'w');
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $num = count($data);
            if($row == 1){array_unshift($data,"Symbol"); }
            else  { array_unshift($data, $symbol); }
            fputcsv($fp, $data);
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($fp);
        fclose($handle);
```

thas how i get the CSV file

Comment: It should never matter what order the rows in your db are as you cannot depend on that. Use order by clauses when retrieving.

Comment: What @Ilion -- relational schemas should be agnostic to storage order.

Comment: Why do you care about the order your transactions are stored?

Comment: i guess the only reason i care is out of habit. Is it not a problem if chunks of dates arent in the same order?

Comment: There is no problem in that. Order it when you retrieve it.

Comment: BTW IMHO using staging (temp) table in this scenario is beneficial irrelevant to the order. It's a convenient way to clean and validate your data before inserting to factual table(s). You might also consider using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for parsing and loading data from your csv files.

Comment: @brandenwagner Routine backend maintenance can often reorder rows in a database so you cannot depend on them being in a specific order or even staying in a specific order. I'm forgetting offhand when this happens in MySQL, but in PostgreSQL for example it happens when vacuum jobs are run to flush unused space due to deleted rows and such.